# Java classes problem (one to many - many to one)?

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to make a program dog register where you can register users and dogs.
The problem that I'm having is to make the different classes work together.

I want to make it so the user can have many dogs, but the dog can only have one user.

And I want to be able to retrieve the dog and the owner in the toString in the classes.

**When I call the toString for my User class it works but not when I try it from the Dog class.**

**UPDATE**
The thing I don't understand is how I'm going to access the owner from the dog class when it's stored in the User class?

What am I doing wrong?

Adding my Dog class

```
    public class Dog{

    private String name, breed;
    private int age, weight;
    private User owner;

    public Dog(String n, String b, int a, int w){

        name = n;
        breed = b;
        age = a;
        weight = w;
    }


    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getBreed(){
        return breed;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public int getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }

    public double getTailLength(){
        if(getBreed().equalsIgnoreCase("Tax") || getBreed().equalsIgnoreCase("Dachshund") ){
            return 3.7;
        }else{
            double d = (getAge()*getWeight()/10.0);
            return d;
        }
    }

    public void increaseAge(int a){
        if(a<getAge()){
            this.age = age;
        }else{
            this.age += a;
        }
    }

    public int testAge(){
        return age += 1;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner){
        User oldOwner = this.owner;
        this.owner = owner;

        if(oldOwner != null && oldOwner != owner){
            oldOwner.removeDog(this);
        }

        if(owner!=null){
            owner.addDog(this);
        }
    }

    public User getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return getName() + " " + getBreed() + " " + getAge() + " år " + getWeight() + " kg svans=" + getTailLength() + getOwner();
    }
}
```

User class

```
public class User{

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Dog> owner = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addDog(Dog d1){
        if(!owner.contains(d1)){
            owner.add(d1);
            d1.setOwner(this);
        }
    }

    public void removeDog(Dog d1){
        if(owner.remove(d1)){
            d1.setOwner(null);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Dog> getDogs(){
        return new ArrayList<Dog>(owner);
    }

    public User(String n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return getName() + " " + getDogs();

    }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? What are you asking about?

Comment: getDogs() will only print out the name of the instance. You need to iterate through dogs and print each of them. But don't just use the Dog's toString() because that would result in infinite loop.

Comment: When i call the toString in my Dog class i get error. Its pointing me to the getOwner() method.

Comment: That `setOwner(User)` in `User` looks out of place and instead of `ArrayList<Dog> owner` in `User` it should be `ArrayList<Dog> dogs` or something similar (so pay attention to the naming of your variables) but in general your approach doesn't look too bad. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that i cant access the owners from the dog class. I cant who is the owner. The toString is crashing when i call it from the dog class but it work in User class

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj no, `getDogs()` won't print anything but return an `ArrayList`. That list's `toString()` is being called and that in turn will iterate over the elements already - so if `Dog.toString()` returns a dog's data only it should be fine. The problem arises if `Dog.toString()` causes `User.toString()` to be called and vice versa, that will result in indefinite cycles.

Comment: You are confusing us and possibly yourself with your naming in the `User` class, calling the list of dogs `owner` is not a good choice instead it should be named either `dogs` or `ownedDogs` or similar. If you rename it and the get/set methods it would be helpful

Comment: Instead of `... + getOwner()` in `Dog.toString()` you might want to consider getting the owner's name only, e.g. ` + (owner != null ? owner.getName() : "")`.

Comment: Ah the good old pet/owner example teachers use to teach object programming.. A good habit to take from the start: be careful about names you choose, they must not confuse people. And keep a mental tracking of what is calling what. Don't hesitate to put things on a paper..

Comment: @Thomas when i call the Dog.toString() i want to get the owners name and all the dogs that owner have.

Comment: Yes, i've had a feeling i made it a bit confusing withe the naming.... the thing i don't understand is how i'm going to access the owner from the dog class when its stored in the User class

Comment: If the questions spawns dozens of comments asking for clarifications, that means the question is not clear. Don't put clarifications piece-by-piece in each comment, edit your question.

Comment: @J-Alex Sorry, first time posting a question. I'm updating my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I think you should solve this, first the Dog class where I have skipped a few attributes for clarity. `toString` only contains the dogs name (and other dog specific attributes I skipped) instead I have a specific method to get the owners name for printing

```
public class Dog {
    String name;
    User owner;

    public Dog(String name) { 
        this.name = name; 
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public User getOwner() { return owner; }

    public void setOwner(User owner) { this.owner = owner; }

    public String ownerAsString() {
        if (getOwner() != null) {
            return getOwner().toString();
        } else {
            return "<No Owner>";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

The User class has a list of dogs and the `toString` method only returns the users name, instead I have a specific method to get the owned dogs as a string. This is to not get circular references between User and Dog when printing.

```
public class User {
    String name;
    List<Dog> ownedDogs;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        ownedDogs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Dog> getOwnedDogs() {
        return ownedDogs;
    }

    public void setOwnedDogs(List<Dog> ownedDogs) {
        this.ownedDogs = ownedDogs;
    }

    public void addDog(Dog dog) {
        ownedDogs.add(dog);
        dog.setOwner(this);
    }

    public String ownedDogsAsString() {
        return ownedDogs.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This can then be used like this

```
User u = new User("abc");
Dog d1 = new Dog("D1");
Dog d2 = new Dog("D2");
u.addDog(d1);
u.addDog(d2);
System.out.println(u + " ownes " + u.getOwnedDogs());
System.out.print(d1 + " is owned by " + d1.ownerAsString());
```

output:

> abc ownes [D1, D2]
>   D1 is owned by abc

Comment: Hi I have tried this option but I still keep getting NullPointerException...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Dog.ownerAsString(Dog.java:71)

Comment: What’s at line 71 in your code? There is no way my code contains that many lines for Dog so I can’t help you without seeing your code.

Comment: With all the specific dog attributes you skipped, I still have in my code and that why there are so many lines. Line 71 is return getOwner().toString(); the code return the owner but then it crashes. Since i have more owners that don't own a dog

Comment: Ah, did you set an owner for the dog in your test code? I’ll update my code with a null check since a dog might not have an owner

Comment: I'm doing a for loop to list all the dogs and get there owner, I think that is why i get NullPointerException cause some dogs don't have an owner

Comment: Sloppy of me to miss the null check, fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much! now it works just as i want it :)

Comment: Nice extensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
 private ArrayList<Dog> owner = new ArrayList<>();
```

that should simply be:

```
 private ArrayList<Dog> ownedDogs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you have methods to add (or remove) Dogs that belong to this user.

And finally:

```
public ArrayList<Dog> getDogs(){
    return new ArrayList<Dog
```

becomes:

```
public ArrayList<Dog> getDogs(){
    return ownedDogs;
}
```

Right now your `getDogs()` returns a new empty list each time you call it. Which doesn't make sense, because you already have that list of "owned" dogs. If at all, you could consider creating new list (that contains all owned dogs), and hand out that. But there is no point in returning an empty list!

Regarding the stackoverflow: you have to make sure that there is no recursion there! When adding a dog to a user ... that adds the user as owner, which adds the dog ... you simply have to break up that chain.

Interestingly enough, this is a very basic problem in OOP dealing with state: you have "double bookkeeping" here, the owner knows his dogs, and all dogs know their owner. So, updating that information in a meaningful way is actually **hard**.

The real answer here: build your model according to reality! My dog doesn't have a built in property that says "owned by Ghostcat". I know "this is my dog", and there is some paper somewhere that says "dog X is owned by Ghostcat". In other words: consider dropping the "owner" field for the dog class.

Comment: I tried that, and get some repeating error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Do you mean i should have one list to store the owners and one list to store the dogs?

Comment: You're getting a StackOverflowError because your `Owner.toString` is calling `getDogs()`, which calls their `toString` methods. Their `toString` methods call `Owner.toString`, so this recursion is causing the stack overflow.

Comment: Okay.... I see. But how do i access get who is the owner from the dog class? I have a feeling my method public User getOwner is not correct.